# How to mock a shirosession?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, shiro

In my project  shiro session is used to authenticate users.I am to write a mock test for a service call. i.e.
    **object.setCreatedBy(SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal().toString())**
which sets loggedin user (such as *sandy*) in CreatedBy field  .Now I want to populate this value from testCase(using Junit 4.0 and easy 3.0).I am using following code

```
public class ExampleShiroUnitTest extends AbstractShiroTest {

@Test
public void testSimple() {
    //1.  Create a mock authenticated Subject instance for the test to run:
    Subject subjectUnderTest = createNiceMock(Subject.class);
    expect(subjectUnderTest.isAuthenticated()).andReturn(true);

    //2. Bind the subject to the current thread:
    setSubject(subjectUnderTest);
}

@After
public void tearDownSubject() {
    //3. Unbind the subject from the current thread:
    clearSubject();
}
```

}

given at  http://shiro.apache.org/testing.html.
In above method subject is set properly and gives proper value when get,but don't know how to get  **principal** out of this. When I access it from subject it return null and there is no method as setPrincipal().

Comment: +1 for mentioning AbstractShiroTest.  I created a non-static wrapper for SecurityUtils so I could mock and inject it, but this would have been nice when I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but doesn't something like this solve the issue?

```
expect(subjectUnderTest.getPrincipal()).andReturn("sandy");
```

Comment: expect(subjectUnderTest.getPrincipal()).andReturn("sandy"); was throwing an error.But expect(subjectUnderTest.getPrincipal()).andReturn("sandy").anyTimes(); worked just fine