# The method expect(boolean) is undefined for the type in Shiro test

Tags: testing, junit, mockito, shiro

I'm doing my first test in Java, and I have a Shiro Security... I follow the tutorial (https://shiro.apache.org/testing.html) but says:

(this example uses EasyMock, but Mockito works equally as well):

```
Subject subjectUnderTest = createNiceMock(Subject.class);
expect(subjectUnderTest.isAuthenticated()).andReturn(true);
```

Because I use Mockito I implement with

```
Subject mockSubject = mock(Subject.class);
expect(subjectUnderTest.isAuthenticated()).andReturn(true);
```

But when I do it have this error

> The method expect(boolean) is undefined for the type AdminControllerTest

And don't give me the posibility to import it. I don't know if expect is especific of EasyMock and if yes what I have to use in Mockito.

I search here and see more person doing it and always recomend use this expect

[How to mock a shirosession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438123/how-to-mock-a-shirosession)

Comment: Please show us your import of `expect`. Do you have one?

Comment: Thanks @Lesiak, but this is the problem... I don't have any import and Eclipse don't suggest where I can import :-(

Comment: If you have static import for `createNiceMock` why don't you try adding one for `expect`. They come from the same class `EasyMock`, it seems not likely that you can import one but not the other

Comment: Thanks again... and I'm sorry... I don't use EasyMock but Mockito (I edit the question), and if I try to import says: The import org.mockito.Mockito.expect cannot be resolved

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392148/what-is-the-mockito-equivalent-of-expect-andreturn-times

Comment: Thanks a lot Lesiak... thats the guide I need.... If you want write the answer and I choose it... if not, I  answer the question myself to help someone need it!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at this code example ...

```
Subject mockSubject = mock(Subject.class);
expect(subjectUnderTest.isAuthenticated()).andReturn(true);
```

We can see that ...

1. You are using `mockito` syntax to do the mocking.
2. You are using `easyMock` syntax to configure the mock. It is not even in the dependency list, so this method is not found.

The solution is to use mockito syntax to configure the mock.

```
Subject mockSubject = mock(Subject.class);
when(mockSubject.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);
```

This will make everything work as expected and your `Subject` will return `true`, when the `isAuthenticated()` method is called.

If you want to up your mockito game, try this [resource](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series), which comes with working github code examples.